# how many c:forEach can we have in 1 jsp file

Tags: spring, jsp

I am having a trouble with my jsp file at the moment, for somehow when i include pagination.jsp, my website goes like this ( but if i don't, everything works well). Can anybody help me with this ?

Here is my original jsp file:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Management</title>
    <jsp:include page="../Common/inlcude.jsp"/>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="../Common/header.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="../Common/sidebar.jsp"/>
<h1 class="col-md-10" style="margin-bottom:20px"> List Of Member </h1>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form style="margin-left: 20px;padding-left : 20px;" class="table table-hover col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" method="GET" action="#" >
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder ='Search user'>
        <input type="submit" name='submit' value='search'>
    </form>
    <table style="margin-left: 0px;padding-left : 0px;" class="table table-hover col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <thead>
        <th>STT</th>
        <th>TenTaiKhoan</th>
        <th>HoTen</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>SDT</th>
        <th>AnhDaiDien</th>
        <th>DiaChi</th>
        <th>GioiTinh</th>
        <th>NgaySinh</th>
        <th>LoaiTaiKhoan</th>
        <th>TrangThai</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
            <td>${user[0]}</td>
            <td>${user[3]}</td>
            <td>${user[4]}</td>
            <td>${user[5]}</td>
            <td><img src="../Resources/Images/${user[1]}" alt="" id="img1" height="150" width="150"></td>
            <td>${user[6]}</td>
            <td>${user[7]}</td>
            <td>${user[8] == 1?"User":"Admin"}</td>
            <td>${user[9]}</td>
            <td>${user[10] == 1?"Actived":"Removed"}</td>
             <td align="center">
                 <a href="${user[0]}.htm?ModifyForm">
                    <img src="../Resources/Images/edit.png">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this')"
                                  href="${user[0]}.htm?Delete"><img src="../Resources/Images/delete.png"/></a></td>
        <tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<jsp:include page="../Common/pagination.jsp"/>
<jsp:include page="../Common/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the pagination.jsp file that i inlcude:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: levub
  Date: 4/10/2020
  Time: 2:40 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<div class="col-lg-10" style="text-align: center;">
    <c:choose>
    <c:forEach var="index" begin="1" end="2">
        <c:when test="${page > index && page - 1 == index}">
            <a class="button" href="UserManagement.htm?page=${page - 1}"></a>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${page <= index && page + 2 >= index}">
            <a class="button" href="UserManagement.htm?page=${index}"></a>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${page < 10 &&  page + 2 == index && 10 - page > 2}">
            <a class="button" href="UserManagement.htm?page=${page + 1}"></a>
        </c:when>
    </c:forEach>
    </c:choose>
</div>
```

And this what i get from my browser when i include it :
[image]

Comment: Check your server for errors. Make sure that al variables are available.

Comment: tks but now i know where the problem comes from. I should have placed <c:choose> below <c:forEach>

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to use  Tag. Also, your nesting of tags is incorrect with c:forEach

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${condition1}">
   //do something if condition1 is true
</c:when>
<c:when test="${condition2}">
    //do something if condition2 is true
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    //Statements which gets executed when all <c:when> tests are false.
</c:otherwise>
```